# Sense of self in clones or copied of digtally uploaded minds

Tags: cloning

Will the clones have sense of self-identity of their own. What would be their relationship with their initiators (I don't know what such initials will be called!Clonees anyone?)If minds are uploaded or artificially created and copied Will this minds have their own selves.What I am asking is What would clone feel about himself Will he always mentally attached to to the initial person,Since he has same and only memories.Same is with uploaded minds.With clones I mean modified copies a person( A LA STAR Wars) with same memory.For mind uploading or Artificial created consciousness please refer to **"Saturns Children" and "Neptunes Brood"** by Charlie Stross.(http://www.antipope.org/charlie/blog-static/fiction/faq.html)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site. However it is quite unclear what are you asking. Can you please expand the question a bit?

Comment: Hi, it would be nice if you could expand on what kind of cloning you want to use. It looks like you are mixing "Just create another clone" with "Upload the original mind and create an organic hull". [This](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/61993/how-do-you-solve-the-copied-consciousness-conundrum-without-killing-anyone?rq=1) question might help you with some aspects of your question. And please have a look at your punctuation

Comment: This was done well in Kiln People.  http://www.davidbrin.com/kilnpeople.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you solve the copied consciousness conundrum without killing anyone?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/61993/809)

Answer (score 3):

Although your question is very poorly worded, I think I know what you're trying to get at, and the answer is that ***yes***, each "clone" would develop its own personality/opinions.

The reason is simple. Imagine that an identical copy of yourself came into existence this very second. You two look alike, think alike, have the same preferences in music, food, and even love the same people.

There's only one problem: only one of you can *be you*. Your wife, girlfriend, children, or job are not something you can *share*. Similarly, from a legal POV only one of you is the "real" you.

And so, from this point on each of you is living their own life. One of you goes home to a loving family, the other is cast out into the world with no real identity, and cut off from all the relationships and possessions it remembers having.

That's a pretty nasty psychological shock. 10 years from now that "clone" will not be the same person "you" are. It will have experienced a completely different life, and been shaped and molded by it.

---

Edit to answer follow up question:

> How will the clone will look at the initial/original. Will he consider him as father or brother or competitor or stranger?

Depends on the circumstances of that clone's creation and existence. Essentially, you set the rules.

Is cloning a wide spread process which has some sort of laws guiding its implementation? As in, are these clones created by the state/company with a certain purpose? Or was your copy created accidentally, due to some experiment.

Was it created in order to be used for "spare parts", or as a citizen with full standing, who is expected to contribute to society? (we needed more super-smart engineers, so we created a copy of you! vs your "owner" needs a new kidney, and you've been created in order to provide it)

There's lots of books out there addressing the moral issues behind cloning, and how it might be implemented in some far flung future. I suggest you establish exactly how you wish cloning to be done, the rules and laws of society regarding cloning and clones, and then ask a better framed question about it all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I will try to improve my question.As a a follow up,how will the clone will look at the initial/original. Will he consider him as father or brother or competitor or stranger

Comment: @uphillPancake - I've updated my answer. You need to make up your mind as to what you want your universe to be like, then a more detailed answer can be given.

Comment: @uphillPancake I think it largely depends on why the clone was created. If I chose to make a clone that would go colonize another planet, I'd be cool with that. But if I went home to discover a clone I didn't know existed had replaced me and I was suddenly cast out as a persona non grata, I would go berserk and kill my clone and probably the people that created him. (And depending on the circumstance, how would I know I'm the original instead of the clone?)

Comment: @AndreiROM [`Man is (...) the sum of his actions`](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/539404-man-is-nothing-else-but-what-he-purposes-he-exists) Clones will be identical for about 2 seconds or as long as it takes for the realization to set in that each is looking at a duplicate of the other. Then experiences start to diverge and the clones cease being identical.